# C++ compliation failing after upgrading XCode to verison 11.1

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm running MacOS 10.14 still but I did upgrade XCode recently so that I'm running XCode 11.1. I have a C++ project that uses CppRestSDK for HTTP and REST. Now when building my project with CMake it fails with the error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework', needed by `<retracted>'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

If I look under: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/`

I only have MacOSX10.15.sdk there and not 10.14 anymore?

I do have this:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework`

I do not want to update MacOS to 10.15 Catalina right now.

Comment: have you tried a clean build? might be a cmake cache around with the wrong path in it

Comment: Yes, I definitely tried a clean build. Deleted the whole build directory and started form a clean build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, xcode 11 comes with the *Catalina* sdk.  Copy the old one over, or download it from https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases

Comment: Maybe I can downgrade XCode then? Should it be downgraded to the last 10.x version of XCode?